# When not to use $\binom{n + r − 1} {r− 1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, multinomial-theorem

The number of non-negative integral solutions of the equation

$x_1+x_2+x_3+....+x_r = n$

is  $\binom{n + r − 1} {r− 1}$

---

I tried using it in the following two questions.

> Let $n_1<n_2<n_3<n_4<n_5$
> be positive integers such that $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5=20$
> . Then the numbers of such distinct arrangements $(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5)$
> is

***Given solution:***

They just listed down all $7$ possible solutions i.e. $(1,2,3,4,10),(1,2,3,5,9),(1,2,3,6,8),(1,2,4,5,8),(1,2,4,6,7),(1,3,4,5,7),(2,3,4,5,6).$

***My approach:***

As for $n_1<n_2<n_3<n_4<n_5$ the condition should be $n_i \geq i$

So let $n_i = x_i + i$ where $x_i \geq 0$

$\therefore (x_1+1)+(x_2+2)+(x_3+3)+(x_4+4)+(x_5+5)=20$

$\therefore (x_1)+(x_2)+(x_3)+(x_4)+(x_5)=5$

Hence number of solution of this equation should be $\binom{5+5-1}{5-1}$

$=\binom{9}{4} = 126$

I think that as $x_i \leq 9-i$ is not considered it's giving extra ways. How do I fix this?

---

In the next question I tried Multinomial Theorem to include both upper and lower bounds.

> A man has three friends. The number of ways he can invite one friend everyday for dinner on six successive nights so that no friend is invited more than three times is?

***Given Solution:***

They did grouping of 6 days of week as $(1,2,3) or (3,3,0) or (2,2,2)$ then permutation of these groups to get final answer as $510$.

**My Approach**:

Let $x_i$ be the number of days $i^{th}$ person goes for dinner, so $0\leq x_i \leq 3$.

$\therefore x_1+x_2+x_3 = 6$

$\therefore$ Number of ways = Coefficient of $p^6$ in $(p^0+p^1+p^2+p^3)^3$

= Coefficient of $p^6$ in $\frac{(1-p^4)^3}{(1-p)^3}$

= Coefficient of $p^6$ in $(1-3p^4 +\text{terms with p power greater than 6})(1-p)^{-3}$

= $\binom{8}{6} - 3\binom{4}{2}$

= 10

Again very huge difference, how to fix this?? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: In the first problem, your approach is simply wrong. Notice that you cannot switch the order of the numbers that solve that equation, e.g. $(1,2,3,4,10)$ is a solution but $(10,1,4,2,3)$ is not. Using the binomial coefficient blindly assumes a lack of order.

Comment: The condition $n_i≥i$ clearly doesn't imply an increasing sequence.  $(3,2)$ satisfies the inequality.

Comment: Ok didn't realise ‍♂️. Is there any other method, besides finding all the cases manually?

Comment: The first question is discussed in the related questions.  See [Number of distinct arrangements $\{n_i\}$ $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < n_4 < n_5$ such that $\sum n_i = 20$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179424/number-of-distinct-arrangements-n-i-n-1n-2n-3n-4n-5-such-that-sum-n?rq=1).  In the second question, you overlooked that the friends are distinct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig How did I overlooked that the friends are distinct?

Comment: Since the friends are distinct, it matters which person is invited on which day, not just how many times each friend is invited.  If there were no restrictions, there would be three choices for the guest on each of the six days, so there would be $3^6$ possible outcomes.

Comment: For part 1, I added an alternative approach to the [MathSE problem cited by N.F.Taussig](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179424/number-of-distinct-arrangements-n-i-n-1n-2n-3n-4n-5-such-that-sum-n/4762688#4762688).